# Синтаксический разбор предложения с "потому что"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксический-разбор

Нужно сделать синтаксический разбор предложения, учебник 10 класса. **А всё потому(,) что слушать гораздо труднее, чем говорить, так как скорость говорения в 4 раза меньше скорости мышления.**
Вопросы:

1. Нужно ли расчленять союз? На мой взгляд нужно, т.к. "а всё" перетягивает ударение на первую часть.
2. Чем является это "а всё"? Союз + частица?
3. Главное предложение - это "А всё потому"? Если это так, то оно неполное односоставное?) Состоит из одного наречия?) Или же "все" можно рассматривать как подлежащее и местоимение... Никогда не сталкивалась с таким.

Прошу прощения за глупые вопросы, но очень хочется разобраться!

Comment: Спасибо! Еще есть маленький вопрос.)  "Говорения", "мышления" - это определение или дополнение? Сколько не читаю на эту тему, путаюсь.

Comment: Nadezhda, мне понравился ваш  маленький вопрос. Попробуйте задать его отдельно, мне интересно, какие будут ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуем найти контекст, он может выглядеть примерно так.

Хороший собеседник должен прежде всего уметь слушать, и это не случайно. Большинство из нас – плохие слушатели. Часто мы только делаем вид, что слушаем, дожидаясь лишь момента, чтобы высказаться самому.  Но почему так происходит? Дело в том, что слушать гораздо труднее, чем говорить. Скорость “говорения” в 4 раза меньше скорости мышления. Поэтому 3/4 возможностей мозга не задействованы в слушании и ищут себе применение. И обычно находят его в посторонних мыслях.

Итак, мы можем **начать  наше предложение следующим образом**:   *Дело в том, что слушать гораздо труднее, чем говорить. Оказывается,  слушать гораздо труднее, чем говорить. А всё потому, что  слушать гораздо труднее, чем говорить.*

Все эти сочетания для текста имеют значение **вводности и поэтому взаимозаменяемы.** В простом предложении они обособлены и выделены ударением, поэтому запятая ставится. Но в сложном предложении возможно другая расстановка ударений (там мы будем выделять ключевые слова).

***А всё  потому  что слУшать // гораздо труднее, чем говорИть, // так как скорость говорЕния //в 4 раза меньше скорости мышлЕния.***

Тогда сочетание «а всё»  (союз + усилительная частица) примыкает к подчинительному союзу, и тогда он не  расчленяется.  То есть получается **присоединительный  осложненный союз**, который выполняет  служебную  функцию.

**Синтаксический разбор**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным причины. Простые предложения в составе СПП осложнены сравнительными  оборотами. В предложении (1):  слушать – подлежащее, труднее – именная часть сказуемого. В предложении (2):  скорость – подлежащее, меньше – именная часть сказуемого.